# Hilfsverb "lassen" + Passiv ohne "werden"

Tags: passive, auxiliary-verb

Betrachten wir die folgenden beiden Sätze

> Der Kapitän lässt das Schiff von Piraten übernehmen.

und

> Der Kapitän lässt das Schiff von Piraten übernommen werden.

Der zweite Satz sollte grammatikalisch richtig sein, aber ich würde nur den ersteren benutzen. Insofern mein Sprachgebrauch nicht abseitig ist, so wird das Passivhilfsverb im Deutschen bei (einigen) Hilfsverben weggelassen.

Ist dies korrekt? Gibt es dazu mehr Informationen?

**Edit:**
Noch ein Beispiel:

> Der Kommandant lässt die Panzer zerstören.

Dieser Satz kann so gedeutet werden, dass die Panzer zerstört werden, oder so dass es die Panzer sind, welche etwas zerstören.

**Noch ein Nachtrag:**
Ich denke der wesentliche Punkt ist, das lassen in zwei verschiedenen Funktionen im Deutschen auftaucht. Dies erklärt dann auch die Ambiguität. Man vergleiche:

> Ich höre die Kinder spielen.
> Ich lasse den Lehrer den Schüler unterrichten
> Der Kapitän lässt das Schiff von Piraten übernommen werden
> Der Kapitän lässt die Piraten das Schiff übernehmen

In den obigen Beispielen handelt es sich wohl ehesten mit einem Accusativus-cum-infinitivo wie im Lateinischen. Auf das Verb folgt ein Akkusativ und ein Infinitiv. Letzterer kann beliebig kompliziert sein, und selber ein Akkusativobjekt enthalten.

Zum anderen können wir lassen im Deutschen auch verwenden wie in:

> Ich lasse spielen.
> Ich lasse die Schüler (von dem Lehrer) unterrichten.
> Der Kapitän lässt das Schiff (von Piraten) übernehmen.

Diese Konstruktion ist auch der Grund, weswegen wir im Deutschen keinen 'Accusativus-cum-infinitivo-passivo' verwenden, da wir eine ökonomischere Struktur haben. Am ehesten kann man die obigen Beispiele auffassen als 'lassen' + Infinitiv. Wenn wir die Satzteile in Klammern auslassen, dann sind die Infinitive

- die Schüler unterrichten
- das Schiff übernehmen

Wenn wir die Satzteile in Klammern auslassen, dann werden die entsprechenden Sätze allerdings mehrdeutig: Werden die Kinder unterrichtet oder unterrichten die Kinder selbst? Wird das Schiff übernommen oder übernimmt das Schiff (metaphorisch o.ä.)

Das scheint als grammatische Struktur zu funktionieren, und die Mehrdeutigkeit zu erklären. Die Rolle der von-Satzanteile ist jedoch verwirrend. Sie sind nicht Teil des Infinitivs, denn

> *die Kinder von dem Lehrer unterrichten

ist kein gültiger Infinitiv, und

> das Schiff von Piraten übernehmen

ist zwar ein gültiger Infinitiv, aber mit völlig anderer Bedeutung als gedacht. In der zweiten grammatikalischen Struktur 'lassen'+Infinitiv wird die handelnde Entität also mittels 'von' ausgedrückt, unter Inkaufnahme von Mehrdeutigkeit ("das Schiff der Piraten übernehmen").

Was mich daran jedoch verwirrt ist die Stellung dieser von-Konstruktion im Satz. Sie kann nur als Einschub in den Infinitiv verstanden werden, da sie wie oben beschrieben nicht Teil des Infinitivs sein kann.

**Fragen:**
Ist solch ein Einschub im Deutschen allgemein zulässig? Gibt es Beispiele in anderen grammatikalischen Situationen? Oder gibt es noch eine andere mögliche Sichtweise auf diese grammatikalische Situation? Es würde mich sehr freuen, falls uns jemand eine gute Abhandlung über das Hilfsverb lassen und seine Verhältnis zum A.c.l. verweisen könnte.

Comment: Auch dein Kommandant-Satz ist ein astreiner Aktiv-Satz, egal wie man ihn deutet. Ob die Panzer selbst etwas tun, oder ob ihnen etwas geschieht ist irrelavant, denn sie sind nicht das Subjekt des Satzes (sie sind ein Akkusativobjekt). Das Subjekt ist der Kommandant. Und der tut etwas (zumindest im grammatischen Sinn): Er *lässt*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich weiß. Und?

Comment: Ist das Verb "lassen" wirklich ein intranstives Verb?
Wenn es so ist, dann dürfte man so etwas nicht sagen: Ich habe den Schlüssel zuhause gelassen. Hier verwenden wir einen Akkusativobjekt! → den Schlüssel ! Das heißt, "lassen" ist ein transtives Verb und wir können es auch im Vorgangspassiv verwenden: Der Schlüssel ist zuhause gelassen worden. Ich denke, dass es möglich wäre, den Satz so zu erweitern: "Ich habe den Schlüssel auf dem Tisch liegen lassen / gelassen." Und "Ich hätte den Schlüssel nicht auf dem Tisch liegen lassen können."

Comment: Dein Beispiel "...läßt das Schiff von Piraten übernommen werden" funktioniert m.A. nach überhaupt nicht oder wenn, dann extrem holprig. (Ich denke du willst sagen "läßt zu, dass das Schiff übernommen wird"?). Im Passiv wird niemand gefragt, ob etwas überhaupt passieren darf - Es passiert einfach. Daher passt "lassen" als Modalverb (logisch, nicht unbedingt grammatisch) nicht.

Answer (score 3):

### Kein Passiv, sondern Aktiv!

Der Satz

> Der Kapitän lässt das Schiff von Piraten übernehmen.

ist nun mal kein Passiv-Satz, sondern ein ganz normaler Aktiv-Satz. Dem Kapitän geschieht nichts, und er erleidet nichts. Im Gegenteil: Der Kapitän tut aktiv etwas.

Vergleiche:

> Der Kapitän lässt ausmahlen.
>   Der Kaiser lässt die Truppen aufmarschieren.

Das Prädikat des Satzes ist eine Form des Verbes »lassen«. Derjenige, der im Satz etwas *lässt* ist der grammatikalische Täter. Das ist in diesem Beispiel eben der Kapitän (»Der Kapitän lässt ...«). Wenn aber der Täter gleichzeitig das Subjekt des Satzes ist, handelt es sich um einen stinknormalen Aktiv-Satz. Und genau das ist hier der Fall.

Und wenn kein Passiv-Satz da ist, kann man auch nicht mit Passiv-Satz-Werkzeugen hantieren.

---

Echte Passiv-Sätze wären:

> Das Schiff des Kapitäns wird von Piraten übernommen.
>   Das Schiff des Kapitäns wird von Piraten übernommen werden.
>
> Der Kapitän des Schiffes wird von Piraten überfallen.
>   Der Kapitän des Schiffes wird von Piraten überfallen werden.

Denn hier erleidet im ersten Beispiel das Schiff etwas (es wird übernommen), und im zweiten Beispiel erleidet der Kapitän etwas (er wird überfallen). Aber in keinem der beiden Sätze *lässt* jemand etwas machen.

---

### Nachtrag: Unterschied Semantik - Grammatik

Hier wird sowohl vom Fragesteller als auch von Autoren anderer Antworten etwas durcheinander gebracht. Es werden Semantik und Grammatik verwechselt.

Beispielsatz:

> Peter lässt sich die Haare schneiden.

Ist das Aktiv oder Passiv?

- Aus Sicht der **Semantik**, also der Lehre von den Bedeutungen:

  Peter liegt faul im Friseurstuhl, während jemand (wir nehmen mal an ein Friseur) mit Kamm und Schere in der Hand um Peter herumtänzelt und dabei dafür sorgt, dass die Haare auf Peters Kopf kürzer werden.

  Der Friseur ist aktiv, denn er bewegt sich, er tut etwas.
  Peter ist passiv, er liegt nur rum und erduldet die Behandlung des Friseurs.

  Das alles ist **Semantik**, denn da geht es **Bedeutungen**. Es geht bei Semantik ausdrücklich *nicht* um Funktionen von Satzteilen innerhalb eines Satzes.

  Merke: Wir machen hier in der Semantik Aussagen über Personen. Wir machen keine Aussagen über Sätze oder Satzteile.
- Aus Sicht der **Grammatik** sieht das anders aus. Denn in der Grammatik reden wir nicht über Bedeutungen, sondern über **Funktionen von Satzteilen**. Das ist, wenn man so will, die technische Sicht auf die Sprache.

  In der Grammatik sind keine Personen oder Dinge aktiv oder passiv, sondern Sätze!

  Jeder vollständige Satz enthält ein Prädikat, das durch ein Verb mit allfälligen Beifügungen realisiert ist. Dieses Verb ist der Herrscher über den ganzen Satz, alles im Satz hat irgendwie mit diesem Verb zu tun.

  An dieses Prädikat sind mehrere andere Satzteile gebunden, die unterschiedliche grammatische Eigenschaften haben können. Welche das sind, hängt vom Verb ab. (Fast) immer vorhanden ist eine Ergänzung des Verbs, die im Nominativ steht. Das ist das Subjekt des Satzes.

  Viele Verben (aber nicht alle!) können zusätzlich eine Ergänzung haben, die im Akkusativ steht. Nur solche Verben, die eine Akkusativergänzung erlauben, können überhaupt in Passiv-Sätzen vorkommen, denn nur in diesem Fall kann das Verb transitiv sein, und genau das ist die Voraussetzung um den Passiv bilden zu können (Zu Ausnahmen siehe weiter unten):

  - transitives Verb mit Akkusativergänzung:

    > Aktiv: Georg mäht den Rasen.
    >   Passiv (mit Dativobjekt): Der Rasen wird von Georg gemäht.
    >   Passiv (ohne Dativobjekt): Der Rasen wird gemäht.
  - intransitives Verb:

    > Aktiv: Georg spricht. Georg spricht mit Ilse.
    >   Passiv: ???
    >
    > Aktiv: Georg schläft. Georg schläft auf dem Sofa.
    >   Passiv: ???

  In allen Aktiv-Sätzen gibt es einen Täter. Das ist jener Satzteil, der die Handlung vollführt, die vom Verb ausgedrückt wird. Das ist in allen Beispielen Georg. Er tut etwas. Mal mäht er (den Rasen), mal spricht er, und dann wieder schläft er. Das grundlegende Wesen eines Aktiv-Satzes ist, dass der Täter und das Subjekt identisch sind.

  Das ist im Passiv-Satz nicht der Fall. Hier ist »der Rasen« das Subjekt (es ist die Nominativergänzung des Prädikats), und der Täter steht, fall er überhaupt erwähnt wird, in einem Dativ-Objekt.

  Noch etwas ist im Passiv-Satz anders: Das Prädikat enthält plötzlich zusätzlich zum Vollverb auch noch ein Hilfsverb (»wird gemäht« statt »mäht«), obwohl wir dieselbe Zeitform (Präsens) verwenden.

  Fällt dir etwas auf? Wir reden hier die ganze Zeit von Subjekten, Objekten, Prädikaten, transitiven und intransitiven Verben usw. Wir reden nicht darüber, ob Personen fleißig oder faul sind. Denn wir befinden uns hier in der Welt der Grammatik.

---

In der Grammtik gibt es aktive **Sätze** und passive **Sätze**. In der Semantik gibt es aktive **Personen** und passive **Personen**. Und selbst wenn der Kapitän, der zulässt, dass Piraten sein Schiff übernehmen, eine passive **Person** ist, so ist der grammatische Satzbau des folgenden **Satzes** dennoch ein Aktiv-Satz wie aus dem Lehrbuch:

> Der Kapitän lässt das Schiff von Piraten übernehmen.

Das Verb »lassen« ist kein transitives Verb und kann keine Akkusativergänzung haben. Es ist wie »sprechen« und »schlafen«: Es ist gar nicht möglich, damit einen Passiv-Satz zu bauen. Daher ist es auch völlig unsinnig, in einem Aktiv-Satz, wie er hier steht, irgendwelche Hilfsverben einfügen zu wollen, die so nur in einen Passiv-Satz eingefügt werden können.

---

**Ausnahmen und Besonderheiten:**
In vielen Fällen kann man auch mit intransitiven Verben den sogenannten »unpersönlichen Passiv« bilden:

> Hier wird nicht geraucht!

(Das ist zugleich auch ein Beispiel für einen Satz, dessen Prädikat »wird nicht geraucht« keine Nominativergänzung hat, wo es im Satz also kein Subjekt gibt.) (Es steht nirgendwo **wer oder was** nicht geraucht wird.)

Verwandt mit dem Passiv ist der Antikausativ (das ist aber kein echter Passiv, sondern in Wahrheit auch nur ein Aktiv-Satz):

> Aktiv: Peter zerbricht die Vase.
>   Antikausativ: Die Vase zerbricht.
>   Passiv: Die Vase wird (von Peter) zerbrochen.
>
> Aktiv: Peter öffnet das Tor.
>   Antikausativ: Das Tor öffnet sich.
>   Passiv: Das Tor wird (von Peter) geöffnet.

Comment: Ich denke, dass geht an meiner Frage vorbei. Im Deutschen gibt es die Konstruktion 'lassen' + Substantiv im Akkusativ + Infinitiv. Merkwürdigerweise ist das Substantiv mal der aktive, mal der passive Teil der Handlung.

Comment: @shuhalo: Ich habe meiner Antwort einen etwas längeren Nachtrag angefügt um zu zeigen, dass meine Antwort eben genau *nicht* an deiner Frage vorbei geht. Deine Frage geht nämlich von einer Prämisse aus, die nicht zutrifft. Deine Prämisse lautet: »Der erste Satz steht im Passiv« das ist aber nicht der Fall. Daher ist deine eigentliche Frage so sinnvoll wie »Warum ist die Erde eine Scheibe?« - Darauf kann man keine vernünftige Antwort geben, denn die Prämisse (»Die Erde ist eine Scheibe.«) trifft nicht zu.

Comment: Nur aus Neugier: _"Der Kapitän lässt ausmahlen."_ Ist _ausmahlen_ ein Begriff aus Schifffahrt/Militär? Die haben ja teils überraschende Begriffe (z.B. _löschen_ für _entladen_).

Comment: @PerlDuck: Nicht dass ich wüsste. Der Kapitän hat irgendwo ein Häuschen am Land, und die Wände im Wohnzimmer sind schon vergilbt. Dagegen will er, *aktiv* wie er nun mal ist, etwas unternehmen, und daher lässt der Kapitän ausmalen.

Comment: Ah, verstehe. Dann ist das "h" in Deiner Antwort nur ein Tippfehler. Interessanter Unterschied dt./österr. übrigens: In D würde man sagen streichen/weißen/malern. "Ausmalen" ist das, was Kinder in Malbüchern tun. Und neuerdings ja auch Erwachsene, wie man hört.

Comment: Du erklärst zwar über Aktiv und Passiv, und die Unterscheidung zwischen Semantik und Grammatik, aber meine Frage bezieht sich auf die Mehrdeutigkeit von Akkusativ + Infinitiv.

Comment: Meine Prämisse ist eben nicht »Der erste Satz steht im Passiv«. Wie um alles in der Welt kommst du darauf?

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, hier könnte derselbe Mechanismus vorhanden sein wie in

> Es lässt sich tun.
>   Es lässt sich nicht sagen
>   Er lässt sich begnügen

Eigentlich könnte man erwarten, dass es

> Es lässt sich tun werden
>   Es lässt sich nicht sagen werden

heißen sollte, was ja aber im Deutschen, meinem Verständnis nach, nicht korrekte Sätze wären.

Ich denke, dass dies darauf beruhen könnte, dass "lassen" *in sich selbst* eine passive eingebaute Bedeutung hat, und dass das "werden" dann unnötig wird.

Zum Vergleich wäre dies vielleicht interessant: Im Schwedischen können wir Sätze mit "låta" (=lassen) sowohl mit oder als auch ohne Passivkonstruktion machen. Wir haben immerhin eine ganz spezielle Passivform von dem Grundverb, das dann gebraucht wird, also ohne weitere Hilfsverben, die "werden" entsprechen sollten.

Comment: Ich denke in deinen Beispielen müsste es mindestens 'Es lässt sich getan werden' and 'Es lässt sich nicht gesagt werden' heissen, um grammatikalisch korrekt zu klingen. Aber danke für die beiden Beispiele.

Answer (score 1):

*Lassen* impliziert eine passive Aktion auf Seiten des Subjekts (das "tut nix", sondern "lässt machen"), und ein anderer Teil im Satz übernimmt das Handeln.

Ist dieses "Handeln" wiederum ein Passiv wie in deinem zweiten Beispiel, dann geht der Sinn verloren - Die Satzteile widersprechen sich semantisch (Der Satz hat semantisch niemanden, der "handelt" und damit logisch kein Prädikat).

Aus rein grammatischer Sicht ist dein zweiter Satz allerdings schon richtig.

> Der Kapitän lässt zu, dass das Schiff von Piraten übernommen wird

Ist zwar sehr ähnlich, aber semantisch wesentlich brauchbarer.

Comment: »Der Kapitän lässt ...« ist doch kein Passiv. Das ist astreiner Aktiv!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Natürlich nicht - Kein "grammatisches Passiv" - Aber eine passive Aktion - Steht aber auch so da. Bei dieser Frage geht es nicht um Grammatik, sondern sprachliche Semantik.

Comment: Das ist der Grammatik aber wurscht. Du bringst Semantik und Grammatik durcheinander. Der zweite Satz des OP (»*Der Kapitän lässt das Schiff von Piraten übernommen werden.*«) ist aus grammatischer Sicht keineswegs richtig, sondern eindeutig falsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Erkläre warum. Der Satz ist grammatikalisch richtig.

Comment: Ich habe das in meiner Antwort erklärt. Das ist ein Aktiv-Satz, an dem man mit irgendwelchen Passiv-Konstrukten rumpfuscht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe nicht "mit passiv-Konstrukten rumgepfuscht". Das verbitte ich mir. Wirklich.

Comment: Ich schrieb nicht, dass du das gemacht hättest, ich schrieb »an dem *man* ...«. Tatsächlich war es ja der Fragesteller.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Doch, der Satz ist grammatikalisch am richtig sein, wenngleich er natürlich nicht idiomatisch am sein ist.