# 'sich lassen' with infinitive and without 'werden'?

Tags: sentence-structure

I've come across the following passage:

> Hier arbeiten Doktoranten wie Paul Hix in einem Original-Labor: "Wir
>   ***lassen uns*** gern über die Schulter ***schauen***. Viele Besucher wissen gar nicht, wie so ein Forscheralltag aussieht, sondern kennen nur die
>   Klischees vom verrückten Forscher aus Hollywood Filmen.

So, Mr Paul is happy to let people take a peak of what he does, in order to dismiss the common perception of scientists as crazy people.
My question is, shouldn't it have said:

> **Wir lassen uns gern über die Schulter geschaut werden.**

?

Or have I completely misunderstood the idiom, and what he actually means is that he likes to look over his shoulder to watch people who, in turn, are watching him work?

Comment: Closely related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33441/hilfsverb-lassen-passiv-ohne-werden/33451#33451

Answer (score 2):

The verb **lassen** already implies the action given in infinitive is done by another person. No passive voice needed nor useful.

> Er arbeitet nicht, er lässt arbeiten.

*He doesn't work, he lets (someone else) work.*

Maybe it helps you to think of this *lassen* as *to let it happen*.

---

Be careful however about its other, highly idiomatic uses:

> Er lässt sich Zeit.

*He takes his time.*

> Lass das! / Lass es sein!

*Stop it!*

> Lass mal fünfe gerade sein!

*"Let five be even." (Let's make an exception, okay?)*